# Gift deed of property from British citizen to Indian father

Tags: india, gifts

I have a British passport and would like to gift a property in India to my Indian father ( I bought in 2010 while I was an Indian citizen). I am mobilsing funds to buy my first property in the UK. Should I gift the property via gift deed to my dad, who then sells it. He will pay capital gains and transfer the money to UK after capital gains tax. OR I give power of attorney to my dad who sells it and gifts it to me or my wife. Which option is better in terms of tax savings please. Thanks

Comment: So, what you are doing is not a gift at all since you expect your Indian father (and presumably not a UK citizen or resident of any kind) to sell the property that you own and give you the proceeds of the sale (less any taxes (and presumably fees))?

Comment: If he has power of attorney and sells it, he doesn't gift the money to you. As he acted on your behalf, it is your money as soon as the sale has happened. He just has to give it to you, but that's not a gift, but a payment of debt.

Comment: Thank you both. How to get a power of attorney here in UK?. Does it have to on stamp duty paper from India?. What additional tax do I pay in UK for the money I receive. Where to get definitive advice please - ? HMRC or any property tax lawyers. Thank you .